# Не работает один и тот же код

Tags: c#, массивы

У меня есть алгоритм, который транспонирует вещественный массив, сначала копируя из него числа во временный массив, а затем обратно заполняя уже транспонированный массив.

Раньше алгоритм вызывался напрямую при нажатии кнопки "транспонировать" и работал абсолютно нормально. Код имел следующий вид:

```
void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//L - строки (5)
//N - столбцы (10)
richTextBox1.Clear();
double[,] tmp = new double[N,L];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < L; j++) {
        tmp[i,j] = M[j,i];
        }
    }
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    string s = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < L; j++) {
        M[i,j] = tmp[i,j];
        }
    }
}
```

Потом я решил перенести транспонирование в **отдельный класс**, где создал статический метод с точно таким же кодом:

```
public static void Transponation(double[,] M, int row, int column) {
double[,] tmp = new double[column,row];
for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
        tmp[i,j] = M[j,i];
        }
    }
for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
        M[i,j] = tmp[i,j];
        }
    }
}
```

А для **кнопки** сделал следующий код:

```
double[,] Array;
void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Clear();
    Class1.Transponation(Array,row,column);
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Class1.PrintArray(Array));
}
```

Теперь, когда я выполняю транспонирование, алгоритм останавливается с ошибкой "индекс находился вне границ массива". Причем компилятор показывает, что выполнение кода останавливается на последнем цикле, когда основной массив копирует все числа из временного. Причем это происходит сразу же, как только копируется нулевой элемент. Где в данном случае я допустил ошибку?

UPD: Заметил, что нормально код работает только с квадратной матрицей, в остальном ошибка

Comment: Что у вас в Array?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, там вещественный массив со случайными числами, размер массива вводит сам пользователь. Заполнение этого массива так же в отдельном методе происходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вы передаете размеры массива переменными, если их можно получить из самого массива? Также, обе копии кода, приведенные в вопросе будут работать для квадратной матрицы, а для прямоугольной - не будут.

Да и само транспонирование можно сделать за 2 цикла, а не за 4. И еще нужно вернуть результат транспонирования как новый массив

```cs
public static double[,] Transpose(double[,] array)
{
    int rows = array.GetLength(0);
    int columns = array.GetLength(1);
    double[,] result = new int[columns, rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            result[j, i] = array[i, j];
    return result;
}
```

Еще принято поля и переменные называть с маленькой буквы, а классы, методы и свойства - с большой.

```cs
array = Class1.Transpose(array);
```

Comment: У меня кроме транспонирования еще есть функция нахождения суммы по столбцам в массиве. Поэтому мне нужно осуществить транспонирование именно в самом массиве, а не в другом.

Comment: @Иван это невозможно для прямоугольной матрицы, но возможно только для квадратной. Невозможно, потому что вы не можете изменить размеры существующего массива. Вам для квадратной надо?

Comment: мне нужно именно для прямоугольной.

Comment: @Иван ну, есть у вас массив 5x10, как вы из него сделаете 10x5? Никак, а можете только новый создать. Или вы имеете в виду какое-то другое транспонирование? Так что для прямоугольной матрицы я вам уже дал решение.

Comment: да, именно так. Было 5 строк и 10 столбцов, стало 10 строк и 5 столбцов.

Comment: @Иван еще вариант создавать квадратный массив по бОльшей стороне, а размеры хранить в отдельных переменных, но я не понимаю, зачем такое выдумывать? У вас же квадратный массив? Иначе ваш код из вопроса просто не работал бы.

Comment: Массив именно прямоугольный и дело в том, что первый код то работает. Он нормально транспонируется и перезаписывается в тот же массив. И без каких-либо ошибок всё выводится на экран.

Comment: @Иван значит вы чего-то не договариваете. При разных N и L у вас будет ошибка "Индекс за пределами", в коде, который "работает". Но вы не показали, как создаете массив. Может вы делаете что-то типа `new M[1000,1000]` откусывая под массив 8 мегабайт оперативной памяти, поэтому и работает. Ну либо у вас N=L.

Comment: хорошо, я сейчас добавлю про создание.

Comment: @Иван `UPD: Заметил, что нормально код работает только с квадратной матрицей, в остальном ошибка` - вот и я о том же. Это проблема обеих копий кода, а не только второго варианта.

Comment: да, мне еще очень много предстоит понять...) Благодарю Вас за ответ и за терпение, мне точно стоит более подробно в этом разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Матрица `M` содержит `row` строк и `column` столбцов, как видно из первого цикла.

А потом, **не изменив её размеры**, вы обращаетесь во втором цикле к `column` строк и `row` столбцов